# PHP - for loop with POST validation

Tags: php, forms, for-loop, validation

I'm new to PHP and I'm doing some very simple apps (testing).
I've got a form with the following code:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  if (empty($_POST["val1"])) {
    $err_val1 = "Error";
  } else {
    $val1 = test_input($_POST["val1"]);
  }
}

function test_input($data) {
  $data = trim($data);
  $data = stripslashes($data);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
  return $data;
}
```

```
<div class='col-lg-1 center'>
<label>1</label>
<input type='text' class='form-control' name='val1'>
<span class='error'><?php echo (!empty($err_val1)) ? 'Error' : '';?></span>
</div>
```

Is there a way to use a for (or foreach) loop? Beacause there are 139 "vals" and I'd like to optimize the code avoiding repeat 139 times the same part.

=========  Edit    =========

I've managed to solved it.

```php
    $errors = [];
    $fields = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3', ...];
    $values = [];
    $values['val1'] = $values['val2'] =$values['val3'] = "";
    
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
      foreach ($fields as $field) {
        if (empty($_POST[$field])) {
          $errors[] = $field;
        } else {
          $values[$field] = $_POST[$field];
        }
      }
    
      if (empty($errors)) {
          ... execute SQL INSERT statement ...
      }
```

THE FORM

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
echo "<div class='col-lg-1 center'>";
echo "<label>".$i."</label>";
echo "<input type='text' class='form-control' name='val".$i."' value='".$values['val' . $i]."'>";
if (in_array('val'.$i, $errors)):
echo "<span class='error'>Error</span>";
endif;
echo "</div>";
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of using `test_input()`? Depending on what you're going to do with the data you get, it can actually cause issues. If you found it in some tutorial, find a different and more modern tutorial. I think it originally comes from w3schools, which is famous for having many really bad guides.

Comment: @M.Eriksson - Thanks for the hint. Collected data is inserted into a MySQL database. I get "vals" from the form and send them to the database. Think it like a survey with 139 questions; each answer can be a numeric value from 1 to 5.

Comment: Then that function will cause more harm than good. Data should be saved "as-is" and only convert it into HTML entities when you output the data in a HTML context. When saving the data in the database, you should use prepared statements with placeholders, which removes the need for any escaping.

Comment: @M.Eriksson - Ok, I removed the harmful function, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a way:

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  for ($i = 1; $i <= 139; $i++) {
    if (empty($_POST["val" . $i])) {
      extract([("err_val" . $i) => "Error"]);
    } else {
      extract([("val" . $i) => test_input($_POST["val" . $i])]);
    }
  }
}
```

The untested code above aims to create err_val (like err_val123) if the corresponding value is empty and val (like val123) if the corresponding value is not empty.

`extract` gets an associative array of key-value pairs and extracts the keys into variables with the same name and the values being assigned to them. Maybe I've done some typos, let me know if this does not work as it is.

But this code is not very much readable, why don't we use arrays instead?

```
$values = [];
$errors = [];
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
  for ($i = 1; $i < 139; $i++) {
    if (empty($_POST["val" . $i])) {
      $errors[$i] = "Error";
    } else {
      $values[$i] = test_input($_POST["val" . $i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {` must be placed outside the loop

Comment: @Pippo - I agree that it would be better, but it's not required so there's no "must".

Comment: Both your examples have issues. 1. Using `extract()` here is different but might work. However, the way you've written it has syntax errors. 2. You define `$vals` but are then using `$values` in the loop. And as the first comment hints at, it would make more sense to have the loop inside the if-statement so you only check the request method once.

Comment: @M.Eriksson thanks for the constructive criticism. These were quick, untested examples, so there were some typos involved, but edited them.

Comment: @Pippo your suggestion is definitely an improvement. It's not necessary though, but it is definitely better to check for the method once rather than 139 times.

Comment: @LajosArpad - Thanks! Your code gives an invalid error, but with that tip I solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We can iterate over the POSTed object like an associative array:

```
foreach($_POST as $key=>$value){
    #sanitize
}
```

You could implement the HTML in this way too, if all the children are equal, or separately for the separation of concerns.